# Debugging IDE's port connection to XDebug: "Waiting to Connect"

Tags: php, netbeans, ide, xdebug, netstat

## Preamble

Like many, I've spent more hours debugging my IDE’s connection to XDebug than I have using XDebug to debug my programs. **I’ve gotten it to work repeatedly**, but every once and a while I get the common [“Waiting to connect” problem](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22Waiting+for+Xdebug+session%22+OR+%22Waiting+to+Connect%22+AND+XDebug). I haven’t been able to localize what causes XDebug to work or fail. I’ve been using ubuntu for two years; I’m neither a noob nor an strace guru. **What am I doing wrong? How can I better debug my IDE’s connection to XDebug?**

---

## Setup

- Ubuntu 10.10
- Netbeans 6.9.1
- PHP 5.3.3-1ubuntu9 with Suhosin-Patch
- Xdebug v2.1.0 with debugclient built Sep 20 2010 from source using the [tailored installation instructions script on xdebug.org](http://xdebug.org/find-binary.php)
- Apache Apache/2.2.16
- Both /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini and /etc/php5/cli/php.ini have:
  - ```
    zend_extension = /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so
    xdebug.remote_enable=1
    xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
    xdebug.remote_mode=req
    xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
    xdebug.remote_port=9000
    xdebug.remote_log=/var/log/xdebug.log
    xdebug.extended_info=1
    xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
    ```

---

## Procedure

### The Problem

I can't explain what causes the problem or when the problem manifests. It begins when I try to debug my project, which causes my dev browser of choice (Chrome) to open to the url of my project with the parameter `XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug`. This causes the page to render normally in chrome while Netbeans reports only “Waiting to Connect.”

### Debugging XDebug

First, with the “Waiting to Connect” message still alive, I’ll try to use netstat to dig around port 9000, which goes *something like* this:

```
$ netstat -an | grep 9000
tcp6       0      0 :::9000                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

I shut down my IDE and try to use two files to help figure out what’s going on: `{webroot}/index.php` contains `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`, and `{webroot}/dbgtest.php` contains the [XDebug installation check script](http://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/howto_check_xdebug_installation):

```
<?php
$address = '127.0.0.1';
$port = 9000;
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) or die('Unable to bind');
socket_listen($sock);
$client = socket_accept($sock);
echo "connection established: $client";
socket_close($client);
socket_close($sock);
?>
```

When I start the XDebug `debugclient` and open `http://127.0.0.1/dbgtest.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=mysession`, I’ll usually get the [regular output](http://paste-bin.com/view/6a9d41b2) and then verify XDebug is connected to the script with netstat in another terminal:

```
$ netstat -an | grep 9000
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          127.0.0.1:34831         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:34831         127.0.0.1:9000          ESTABLISHED
```

Though both of these seem to indicate that the connection has been made, the webpage reads "Unable to bind", which I can't explain. I Ctrl-c to quit debugclient, and netstat at this point verifies that port 9000 has no activity. I fire up Netbeans, open `{webroot}/index.php` and engage the debugger, which opens up `http://127.0.0.1/index.php`. The debugger then usually starts normally. I stop the debugger, go back to my project, and this is where the problem really becomes annoying: some of the time, I can continue debugging my project as normal, and other times, the problem re-emerges and while the “Waiting to Connect” sign is displaying, netstat shows:

```
$ netstat -an | grep 9000
tcp6       0      0 :::9000                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          127.0.0.1:34681         TIME_WAIT
```

Other times, I'll restart my computer, fire up a terminal, and find:

```
$ netstat -an | grep 9000
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9000  
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 9000
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

I'm not familiar enough with network and linux internals to see what this points to. Clearly *something* is using port 9000. What does this mean? Note that despite my settings in php.ini:

```
$ cat /var/log/xdebug.log
cat: /var/log/xdebug.log: No such file or directory
```

#### What is the correct way to debug the connection between the IDE and XDebug?

Comment: Sidenote, although your troubles seem to not fully apply here: I've been using fake vhosts (added to hosts file to resolve to 127.0.0.1) and debug on apache vhosts of the same ServerName/Alias, and it works like a charm with Xdebug. A setting to make sure you have set properlty is Project Properties --> Sources --> Web Root, and Sources --> Project URL/Index File so that your browser's /index.php corresponds to the one Xdebug expects in.

Comment: I had a smilar issue and it was the blindingly obvious: xdebug not installed. NetBeans silently assumes that xdebug is present, it never checks. So if some other NetBeans novice is having this issue, check that first :)

Answer (score 5):

If you by chance use the Cisco VPN client, this could be a cause. It comes with a firewall, which is always on, even if the client is not started.
It can be unchecked in the Options menu.

Answer (score 4):

Please read this thread.

http://forums.netbeans.org/post-99369.html

in the end the workaround was to add net.ipv6.bindv6only = 0  to the file /etc/sysctl.d/bindv6only.conf and then reboot. Xdebug worked fine after that.

Comment: Interesting - I'll have to check this out when I investigate XDebug again; I'll mark the answer correct when I've done that (since I posted this I haven't used XDebug).

Comment: Wow, I've been working for hours and this fixed my issue, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Well, my development-set up somewhat differs from yours but I very well know this problem. In fact I just solved it ... this time my Fireeall blocked the port XDebug uses to talk to my IDE.

Some things come to my mind when reading your account:

1) "I can't explain what causes the problem or **when the problem manifests**."
This is a very important statement b/c, as we all know, technichal solutions are strictly dependant on wheather the underlying problem occurs always or sometimes, in a seemingly random fashion. So ... can you sometimes perform XDebugging this way or never?

2) When your IDE is waiting and your browser renders the site immediately, then I guess there is something wrong with your IDE telling your XDebug-server to start. B/c if XDebug would start and couldn't connect back to your XDebug-client then the web-site wouldn't render immediately. But in your case the GET-parameters are just ignored b/c they have no meaning for your Apache/PHP-server as they don't know anything about some XDebug-session you would like to start.

3) Your solution approaches seem very complicated to me. I would keep at simple as possible first and see how that works. For example "xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug" is usually not necassary for a first setup.

Those are my two cents

Best
Raffael