# Netbeans waiting for connection to XDEBUG

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug

Netbeans won't connect to xdebug. I've tried suggestions from the following posts:

[Debugging IDE's port connection to XDebug: "Waiting to Connect"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955226/debugging-ides-port-connection-to-xdebug-waiting-to-connect)

[netbeans shows "Waiting For Connection (netbeans-xdebug)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613726/netbeans-shows-waiting-for-connection-netbeans-xdebug)

but it doesn't fix my issue.

It seems Netbeans connects to xdebug because while it waits for the connection all request made to the webserver [Apache2] are blocked. Also the port [9001] appears to be in use:

```
roxy@Pixy011 ~ $ sudo nmap -sS -O 127.0.0.1

Starting Nmap 6.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-11-28 20:48 EST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000029s latency).
Not shown: 990 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
139/tcp  open  netbios-ssn
443/tcp  open  https
445/tcp  open  microsoft-ds
631/tcp  open  ipp
902/tcp  open  iss-realsecure
3306/tcp open  mysql
8080/tcp open  http-proxy
8081/tcp open  blackice-icecap
9001/tcp open  tor-orport   <---- Opened by java
```

xdebug.ini: [I have confirmed it is loaded in phpinfo()]

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20100525/xdebug.so

xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_mode="req"
xdebug.remote_host="127.0.0.1"
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
```

Netbeans configuration:

```
Debugger port: 9001
Session ID: netbeans-xdebug
Stop at first line: Checked
All other options are unchecked
```

Project properties:

```
Host: 127.0.0.1
Port: 9001
```

Edit:
I've  noticed Netbeans doesn't append the XDEBUG_SESSION_STOP to the URL. I don't think this is related to the issue because Netbeans only opens the page after I close the debugging session.

I've also disabled SELinux

Comment: I spent a little time to debug this and finally found that the issue was that when netbeans launches xdebug it goes to HTTP://LOCALHOST?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug and there was an htaccess that messed with redirect. So changing host to HTTP://LOCALHOST/index.php resulted in getting it to work. So HTTP://LOCALHOST/index.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug

Comment: For me, I didn't know that there were THREE locations where I had to specify port = 9000, and the mismatch was causing “Waiting For Connection (netbeans-xdebug)”: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41768167/470749

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**On Ubuntu 13.04 64bit php 5.4.9-4  Xdebug v2.2.3 netbeans 7.4**
I have same problem and have solve it by:
1. go on http://xdebug.org/wizard.php follow the instructions to compile your own xdebug.so
2. in netbean 7.4 general options (sorry I haven't reputation 10 to post image)
test connection. be sure correct settings on Proxy:
to me "No Proxy" is working.
3. in php options debugging tab change xdebug setting port to other than 9001 or 9000.
I choose 9002 but you can try until you find a free port (if port is not free nb tell you)
4. in php.ini **OR** for **ubuntu users** in /etc/php5/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini

> zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20100525/xdebug.so #where you ave put your reconpiled xdebug.so
>   [xdebug]
>   xdebug.remote_autostart=0
>   xdebug.remote_enable=1
>   xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
>   xdebug.remote_mode="req"
>   xdebug.remote_port=9002 # the port you have found free and set in netbeans above
>   xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
>   xdebug.profiler_enable=0
>   xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/tmp/"
>   xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
>   xdebug.remote_log="/home/#user_name#/xdebug.log" #your user name

5. sudo service apache2 restart

after do this I can debug php again.

Comment: Thanks Leonardo. I skipped 1 (wanted to know if I could avoid that) and it worked. Going back and testing each changes one by one it seems only the port was preventing the connection.

Comment: I have try and work by using xdebug 2.2.1 So you can peek it by apt-get install php5-xdebug
but do step 1 is very simple and so you can use the last xdebug.

Comment: I have previously intall nb 7.4 in my pc and after intalled it I have found that the previous setting on proxy default system is no more good for xdebug: I have to put on no proxy! The change on port number is mandatory. I have do same test to find if the port 9001 was free but they have fail. so to my opinion is better to try a port until success :-)

Comment: For anyone coming later, I am on WAMP and using their default PHP.ini and the only changes I needed to get NetBeans working was this:
`xdebug.remote_enable = on`

Comment: xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_host=localhost

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I have tried many solution i had found out there but the issue still occured. I have tried to follow the step discribe in [enter link description here](https://edmondscommerce.github.io/netbeans/netbeans-xdebug-waiting-for-connection-ubuntu-12-04-mint13-solution.html)

and

[enter link description here](http://www.devside.net/wamp-server/netbeans-waiting-for-connection-netbeans-xdebug-issue)

And that , whttp://localhost/abc/trunk/abc/backend/web/?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebughen i debug my project, my netbeats still waiting connection till i have to had the following "?**XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug**" in my url as **http://localhost/abc/trunk/abc/backend/web/?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug**
so netbeans was able to connect with xdebug

Answer (score 1):

**On Windows 10 with Netbeans 8.0 running Netbeans built in webserver **

The following options in the php.ini file resolved the issue for me:

zend_extension ='C:\path to php installation\ext\php_xdebug-2.5.0-5.6-vc11.dll'
xdebug.remote_enable=on

This issue for me seemed to be resolved by using the full path to the .dll file.  Also, because I had spaces in the path name I had to enclose the path in quotes (double vs single did not seem to matter).  Also, I had to set the xdebug.remote_enable option.  Once I set both options, I was able to select the Debug Application option within Netbeans and the debugger started.

Comment: As this is a popular question, I think it would be relevant for you to review [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Please add some references and broaden your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

i was facing a similar problem, in my case i had recently update my php version and the xdebug configuration were in the only php5 folder. had simply had to copy the old xdebug configuration to the new php.ini file of the new version and it worked like before.

some of the tips to debug this are:

1. first check if xdebug is install, run (php -v) if xdebug details aren't there then install and add the configuration.
2. open phpinfo() under xdebug category check if xdebug configuration is loaded.Check for the following settings.

   - remote_enable = on,remote_handler=dbgp

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue to get xdebug worked in virtualbox ubuntu machine with Netbeans.

PHP version 7.4

Changed following file

```
"/etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini"
```

and added following lines

```
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/20190902/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_log = "/var/log/xdebug.log"
```

Plese note that the line below consists double quotes for defining the path.

```
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/20190902/xdebug.so"
```

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue:

```
$ netstat | grep 9000
...
tcp6       1      0 localhost:9000          localhost:37486         CLOSE_WAIT
```

Solution: Restart NetBeans.
There was running a dead Process waiting for connections.

Here Netbeans with a running debug session. Note the **CLOSE_WAIT** and **TIME_WAIT**.

```
tcp6       0      0 localhost:9000          localhost:38166         TIME_WAIT
```

Comment: That is the same problem i have. always end up with dead connection after few runs. only solution is to restart nb. looking for other solution. if you find any pls do tell.

Answer (score 0):

**For Xdebug v>=3**

If you are still facing issues after trying all above answers. And you have Xdebug version >=3 then only try my steps.

Some settings have been changed in  v3.

1. Xdebug's default debugging port has changed from `9000` to `9003`. So change it in php.ini and netbeans IDE.
2. In php.ini

- add `xdebug.start_with_request="yes"`
- add `xdebug.client_host = localhost` . (The old `xdebug.remote_host=localhost` is no longer useful in v3)
- add `xdebug.mode=debug`