# Impossible debugging a laravel project in netbeans with xdebug

Tags: laravel, netbeans, xdebug, netbeans-8.2, netbeans-11

I try to debug a laravel 5.6 project in Netbeans 8.2 or Netbeans 11 but xdebug is not recognized : Waiting for connection ...
It works with others PHP projects !
Thank's for your help

Comment: What steps have you tried to debug the issue? You're going to need some supporting information for people to assist you!

Comment: I created a new project with existing code => OK

Comment: I created a new project with existing code => OK, php.ini is correctly configured, When I start debugging the message Waiting for connection is displayed. I tried with a classic PHP application and it works fine ! What's the problem with Laravel ?

Comment: Have you checked out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20277240/netbeans-waiting-for-connection-to-xdebug) ?

Comment: Also... what are you trying to debug? Is there something specific that isn't working? Laravel is pretty straight forward with [amazing documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8)

Comment: I guess problem is that xdebug by default thinks that apache is on port 80 but laravel builtin web server is on port 8000. So when you start debugging it open http://localhost/[yours_site]/[your_default_index|page_called] whereas it actually http://localhost:8000/[default_page|page_called]